# type 'NULL' is not a subtype of type 'bool' // main.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new here, I joined the server because I have an error that I can't decipher.

here is the error, when i click on the user i would like to chat with i should get to the chat page. But I have an error that displays "type 'NULL' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Could you help me ?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'MaShup',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          color: appBarColor,
        ),
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => generateRoute(settings),
      home: ref.watch(userDataAuthProvider).when(
        data: (user) {
          if (user == null) {
            return const LandingScreen();
          }
          return const MobileLayoutScreen();
        },
        error: (err, trace) {
          return ErrorScreen(
            error: err.toString(),
          );
        },
        loading: () => const Loader(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error 1
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Error 2

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

screen of emulator

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I redid the chat page as well as the chat controller and the chat repository, but that doesn't change anything...

I searched on stackoverflow and found different things but nothing conclusive... can you help me?

**Landing_screen**

```
class LandingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const LandingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void navigateToLoginScreen(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.routeName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text(
              'Welcome to MaShup',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 33,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height / 9),
            const Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/bg.png'),
              height: 340,
              width: 340,
              color: tabColor,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height / 9),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text(
                'Read our Privacy Policy. Tap "Agree and continue" to accept the Terms of Service.',
                style: TextStyle(color: greyColor),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            SizedBox(
              width: size.width * 0.75,
              child: CustomButton(
                text: 'AGREE AND CONTINUE',
                onPressed: () => navigateToLoginScreen(context),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Mobile_layout_screen**

```
class MobileLayoutScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const MobileLayoutScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<MobileLayoutScreen> createState() => _MobileLayoutScreenState();
}

class _MobileLayoutScreenState extends ConsumerState<MobileLayoutScreen>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver, TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabBarController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabBarController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        ref.read(authControllerProvider).setUserState(true);
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
        ref.read(authControllerProvider).setUserState(false);
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: appBarColor,
          centerTitle: false,
          title: const Text(
            'MaShup',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.grey),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            PopupMenuButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.more_vert,
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context) => [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: const Text(
                    'Create Group',
                  ),
                  onTap: () => Future(
                        () => Navigator.pushNamed(
                        context, CreateGroupScreen.routeName),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
          bottom: TabBar(
            controller: tabBarController,
            indicatorColor: tabColor,
            indicatorWeight: 4,
            labelColor: tabColor,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
            labelStyle: const TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            tabs: const [
              Tab(
                text: 'CHATS',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'STATUS',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'CALLS',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: tabBarController,
          children: const [
            ContactsList(),
            //StatusContactsScreen(),
            Text('Calls')
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            if (tabBarController.index == 0) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, SelectContactsScreen.routeName);
            } else {
              File? pickedImage = await pickImageFromGallery(context);
              if (pickedImage != null) {
                /*Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  ConfirmStatusScreen.routeName,
                  arguments: pickedImage,
                );*/
              }
            }
          },
          backgroundColor: tabColor,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.comment,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Contact_list**

```
class ContactsList extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ContactsList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<Group>>(
                stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).chatGroups(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Loader();
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var groupData = snapshot.data![index];

                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context,
                                MobileChatScreen.routeName,
                                arguments: {
                                  'name': groupData.name,
                                  'uid': groupData.groupId,
                                  'isGroupChat': true,
                                  'profilePic': groupData.groupPic,
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  groupData.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    groupData.lastMessage,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    groupData.groupPic,
                                  ),
                                  radius: 30,
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  DateFormat.Hm().format(groupData.timeSent),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(color: dividerColor, indent: 85),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
            StreamBuilder<List<ChatContact>>(
                stream: ref.watch(chatControllerProvider).chatContacts(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Loader();
                  }

                  return ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var chatContactData = snapshot.data![index];

                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                context,
                                MobileChatScreen.routeName,
                                arguments: {
                                  'name': chatContactData.name,
                                  'uid': chatContactData.contactId,
                                  'isGroupChat': false,
                                  'profilePic': chatContactData.profilePic,
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  chatContactData.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    chatContactData.lastMessage,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    chatContactData.profilePic,
                                  ),
                                  radius: 30,
                                ),
                                trailing: Text(
                                  DateFormat.Hm()
                                      .format(chatContactData.timeSent),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Divider(color: dividerColor, indent: 85),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**select_contact_screen**

```
final selectContactsRepositoryProvider = Provider(
      (ref) => SelectContactRepository(
    firestore: FirebaseFirestore.instance,
  ),
);

class SelectContactRepository {
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  SelectContactRepository({
    required this.firestore,
  });

  Future<List<Contact>> getContacts() async {
    List<Contact> contacts = [];
    try {
      if (await FlutterContacts.requestPermission()) {
        contacts = await FlutterContacts.getContacts(withProperties: true);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
    return contacts;
  }

  void selectContact(Contact selectedContact, BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      var userCollection = await firestore.collection('users').get();
      bool isFound = false;

      for (var document in userCollection.docs) {
        var userData = UserModel.fromMap(document.data());
        String selectedPhoneNum = selectedContact.phones[0].number.replaceAll(
          ' ',
          '',
        );
        if (selectedPhoneNum == userData.phoneNumber) {
          isFound = true;
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            MobileChatScreen.routeName,
            arguments: {
              'name': userData.name,
              'uid': userData.uid,
            },
          );
        }
      }

      if (!isFound) {
        showSnackBar(
          context: context,
          content: 'This number does not exist on this app.',
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context: context, content: e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I added select contact screen because it is from there that it shows me an error.

**router.dart**

```
Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
  switch (settings.name) {
    case LoginScreen.routeName:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const LoginScreen(),
      );
    case OTPScreen.routeName:
      final verificationId = settings.arguments as String;
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => OTPScreen(
          verificationId: verificationId,
        ),
      );
    case UserInformationScreen.routeName:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const UserInformationScreen(),
      );
    case SelectContactsScreen.routeName:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const SelectContactsScreen(),
      );
    case MobileChatScreen.routeName:
      final arguments = settings.arguments as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final name = arguments['name'];
      final uid = arguments['uid'];
      final isGroupChat = arguments['isGroupChat'];
      final profilePic = arguments['profilePic'];
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MobileChatScreen(
          name: name,
          uid: uid,
          isGroupChat: isGroupChat,
          profilePic: profilePic,
        ),
      );
    case ConfirmStatusScreen.routeName:
      final file = settings.arguments as File;
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ConfirmStatusScreen(
          file: file,
        ),
      );
    case StatusScreen.routeName:
      final status = settings.arguments as Status;
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => StatusScreen(
          status: status,
        ),
      );
    case CreateGroupScreen.routeName:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const CreateGroupScreen(),
      );
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const Scaffold(
          body: ErrorScreen(error: 'This page doesn\'t exist'),
        ),
      );
  }
```

**select_contact_group**

```
final selectedGroupContacts = StateProvider<List<Contact>>((ref) => []);

class SelectContactsGroup extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const SelectContactsGroup({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() =>
      _SelectContactsGroupState();
}

class _SelectContactsGroupState extends ConsumerState<SelectContactsGroup> {
  List<int> selectedContactsIndex = [];

  void selectContact(int index, Contact contact) {
    if (selectedContactsIndex.contains(index)) {
      selectedContactsIndex.removeAt(index);
    } else {
      selectedContactsIndex.add(index);
    }
    setState(() {});
    ref
        .read(selectedGroupContacts.state)
        .update((state) => [...state, contact]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ref.watch(getContactsProvider).when(
      data: (contactList) => Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: contactList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final contact = contactList[index];
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () => selectContact(index, contact),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      contact.displayName,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    leading: selectedContactsIndex.contains(index)
                        ? IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.done),
                    )
                        : null,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      ),
      error: (err, trace) => ErrorScreen(
        error: err.toString(),
      ),
      loading: () => const Loader(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: which line is causing this error?

Comment: The issue isnt from here, can you include `LandingScreen` and  `MobileLayoutScreen`

Comment: I don't know, I can't decipher this error.... if you click on error 1 error 2 you will see the detail of the error

Comment: I added Landing Screen and Mobile Layout Screen @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the 1st error message, you need to have the same number of children on TabBar and TabBarView. Add another widget.

```dart
  body: TabBarView(
          controller: tabBarController,
          children: const [
            ContactsList(),
            StatusContactsScreen(), //just unncomment it
            Text('Calls')
          ],
        ),
```

For the second error, it can be inside `ContactsList` I am not sure

Comment: I added ContactList

Comment: For the first error: thank you it worked :) For the second error, I don't understand what is causing the error

Comment: I added select_contact_repository

Comment: sorry not sure about that, try to check route

Comment: I added router.dart

Comment: I added select_contacts_group

Comment: Do you have another idea ?

Comment: it is getting null some point where it is supposed to be a bool (true or false)